# Inequality Involving Supremum of Expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X, Y$ be two random variables and $f$ be a continuous function. If for any realization $X=x$, we have
$$ 
\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)] \leq \sup_{x} \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]
$$
I was wondering if we can conclude that $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)] \leq \sup_x \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]?$

I guess it is fine, by something like substitution law for conditional expectation, but not pretty sure...Any comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What should $\sup_X$ mean for a r.v. $X$?

Comment: @Gono, My bad. I mean $\sup_x \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]$. I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that the assumption about particular realisations is vacuously true ($\mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega_0), Y)] \leq \sup_{\omega \in \Omega} \mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega), Y)]$ trivially- I have assumed $X$ and $Y$ are defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$).

We will choose $X = Y$ to be Rademacher variables, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X = -1) = \frac{1}{2},$ supported on exactly these two points and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ $f(x, y) := xy,$ which is clearly continuous. Note that $\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1.$ However, all the possible realisations for $X$ are $1$ and $-1$ and we have that $\mathbb{E}[f(1, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[f(-1, Y)] = \mathbb{E}[X] = 0,$ so it is not true that $\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] \leq \sup_{\omega \in \Omega} \mathbb{E}[f(X(\omega), Y)].$

Comment: Very nice! I see it totally. Thanks a lot! @Actually Fritz. Then I am wondering when can make the inequality true? Perhaps, if $X,Y$ be nonnegative might work?